# Cannot onmessage with SSE (Java Servlet + ES6 JS)

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee, long-polling, payara

I was trying to make an example of SSE like in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhCKCKD0KnA

```
    response.setContentType("text/event-stream");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    PrintWriter printWriter = null;

    while(true) {

        try {
            double rnd = Math.random() * 10000;

            printWriter = response.getWriter();
            printWriter.print("Rnd: " + rnd);

            response.flushBuffer();


            Thread.sleep(5000);

        }
        catch(IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            printWriter.close();

            break;
        }


    }
```

And client side

```
    window.onload = function () {

        startButton.onclick = () => {
            eventSource = new EventSource('http://localhost:8080/byteslounge-1/sse_test');

            eventSource.onopen = () => {
                displayTextArea.value += 'connected...' + '\n';
            };

            eventSource.onmessage = (message) => {
                displayTextArea.value += message.data + '\n\n';
            };

            eventSource.onerror = () => {
                displayTextArea.value += 'error occured...' + '\n';
            };

            startButton.disabled = true;
        };

        takeMsg.onclick = () => {
            eventSource.onmessage = (message) => {
                displayTextArea.value += message.data + '\n\n';
            };
        };

        stopButton.onclick = () => {
            eventSource.close();
            startButton.disabled = false;
        };

        clearText.onclick = () => {
            displayTextArea.value = '';
        }

    }
```

Connection is ok, but cannot recieve any data in onMessage. No errors/warnings on the server/client. I'm using FF 64 bit last version/JDK 1.8/Payara.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any obvious problem in your code. However, when using Payara 5, I recommend using JAX-RS SSE API instead of coding it yourself in a servlet.

See an example and guide here: http://ridingthecrest.com/blog/2017/02/22/jax-rs-2_1-new-feature-introduction.html

An alternative of your server endpoint with JAX-RS SSE:

```
@Path("server-sent-events")
@Singleton
public class ServerSentEventsResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    public void getMessageQueue(@Context SseEventSink eventSink, @Context Sse sse) {

      while(true) {

        try {
            double rnd = Math.random() * 10000;

            eventSink.send(sse.newEvent("custom-message"));

            Thread.sleep(5000);

        }
        catch(IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            printWriter.close();

            break;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Also test the server endpoint with an generic SSE client, e.g. curl supports SSE and prints incoming events as they come. If that works, then your javascript client has an error.

Comment: The problem was in this line: printWriter.print("Rnd: " + rnd);
I haven't idea, but it works like this (with a string "data: " before and \n\n after): out.write("data: Rnd: " + String.valueOf(str_rnd) + "\n\n"); //data: and \n\n are mandatory

Comment: Obviously, I missed that. The SSE requires that events are prefixed by "\n\ndata: " so that the client can identify them. That's why it's better to use an API that supports SSE directly, like JAX-RS 2.1 in Payara 5 :)

Comment: Also if behind Nginx you must add this response in your header. Else Nginx will buffer SSE response and it will not work properly :response.setHeader("X-Accel-Buffering","no");